# Group-by, aggregate to create a new column based on conditions

Tags: r

Here is the data

```
DPS Comodity    Std Issue
111 Hard drive  No Post
111 MBD         NoBoot
111 LCD         Flicker
222 MBD         No Post
222 LCD         No Post
333 MBD         No power
```

I have to get in the below format

```
DPS Comodity            Std Issue
111 Hard drive,MBD,LCD  Hard drive-No Post,MBD-NoBoot,LCD-Flicker
222 MBD,LCD                 No Post
333 MBD                 No Power
```

I have tried `aggregate(Std Issue~DPS,df,function(x)toString(uniqe(x)))`, but it results Std Issue as

```
No Post,No Boot, Flicker
No Post
No Power
```

Which is not as per my requirement, any suggestion on it to solve this type of problem will be much helpful and appreciated.

```
aggregate(Std Issue~DPS,df,function(x)toString(uniqe(x)))
```

or

Here is the expected result

```
DPS Comodity            Std Issue
111 Hard drive,MBD,LCD  Hard drive-No Post,MBD-NoBoot,LCD-Flicker
222 MBD,LCD                 No Post
333 MBD                 No Power
```

Comment: Where is `uniqe` from? Could you share your data with `dput`?

Comment: Thanks NelsonGon , for every unique DPS , the std Issue- row1 should be : Hard drive-No Post ; MBD-No boot, LCD-Flicker . Row 2 nd of Std Issue column should have only "No Post", as for both Comodity (MBD,LCD) of 2nd row are No Post , and for 3rd row of Std Issue column should be No Power

Comment: But, there might be some pattern to recognize 2nd and 3rd row output. Please explain why your output should look like this on your second or third row to understand clearly.

Comment: @Rushabh :  I need to create a new column that should have values in the form of comodity-std Issue for all such cases where different std issues are encountered for each DPS. If the std issues are same for a particular DPS then new column for that row should have only the value of std Issue. I hope this time i am able to clarify, kindly suggest solution for this. Many thanks for giving your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `data.table` package-

```
  > library(data.table)
  > setDT(dt)[,Std_Issue:=paste0(Comodity,"-",Std.Issue)]
  > setDT(dt)[, list(Comodity = paste(Comodity, collapse=","),
             `Std Issue` = paste(Std_Issue, collapse=",")), by = DPS]
```

**Output**-

```
DPS           Comodity                                 Std Issue
1: 111 Hard drive,MBD,LCD     Hard drive-No Post,MBD-NoBoot,LCD-Flicker
2: 222            MBD,LCD                   MBD-No Post,LCD-No Post
3: 333                MBD                              MBD-No power
```

**Input data-**

```
dt <- read.table(text="DPS  Comodity    Std Issue
111 Hard drive  No Post
                 111    MBD NoBoot
                 111    LCD Flicker
                 222    MBD No Post
                 222    LCD No Post
                 333    MBD No power",header=T,sep="\t")
```

**EDITED-**

You can achieve this using without `for loop`-

```
> setDT(dt)[,Std_Issue:=paste0(Comodity,"-",Std.Issue)]
> setDT(dt)[, list(Std_issue = ifelse(length(unlist(unique(lapply(str_split(Std_Issue,"-"),function(x)x[2]))))<3,paste(unique(`Std.Issue`), collapse=","),paste(Std_Issue, collapse=",")),Commodity=paste(Comodity, collapse=",")), by=DPS]

   DPS                            Std_issue                  Commodity
1: 111       Hard drive-No Post,MBD-NoBoot,LCD-Flicker   Hard drive,MBD,LCD
2: 222                              No Post                   MBD,LCD
3: 333                              No power                    MBD
```

Comment: Thanks Rushabh , but I need the output like this : the Std Issue_new column should have value as : Hard drive-No Post ,MBD-NoBoot,LCD-Flicker; No Post; No Power. The logic is for every row of commodity the new column should have comodity-std issue when different std issue is found in the same row . If same Std issue is found then new column should have only unique Std Issue in the new column . I hope it makes more clear now, Please share your input \ feedback to get solution like this.

Comment: @Ankit I have updated answer with your desired output.

Comment: :@Rushabh :  the output should be for the new column should have  :Hard drive-No Post,MBD-NoBoot,LCD-Flicker for DPS 111 ; for DPS 222 it should contain only No Post ; for DPS 333 should contain No Power . The logic behind this is if for each unique DPS the new column will have comodity-std issues only when there are different std issue , else only paste std issue.

Comment: Thanks , I have written the code but didn't know how to post in the correct format , thanks for making the post more clear. Also can you please let me know if i have to show the result of my code to public, how do i do over here, can i share screenshot or image file of result ?

Comment: @You can just copy paste your output and format it as code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr` to apply to both columns, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 group_by(DPS) %>% 
 summarise_all(funs(toString(unique(.))))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>     DPS Comodity             Std_Issue               
>   <int> <chr>                <chr>                   
> 1   111 Hard_drive, MBD, LCD No_Post, NoBoot, Flicker
> 2   222 MBD, LCD             No_Post                 
> 3   333 MBD                  No_power
> ```

Comment: Thanks Sotos, but this not what i want in output. The Std_Issue column should have values Hard_drive-No_Post,MBD-NoBoot, LCD-Flicker  in 1st row. For 2nd row of Std_Issue should have only No_Post , and 3rd row should have No_power

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution which worked :

```
test_df <- data.frame(DPS=c(111,111,111,222,222,333),comodity =c("HDD","MBD","LCD","MBD","LCD","MBD"),stdIss=c("No Post","No Boot","Flicker","No Post","No Post","No Power"))
A <- data.frame(tapply(test_df$comodity,test_df$DPS,FUN = function(x){toString(x)}))
B <- data.frame(tapply(test_df$stdIss,test_df$DPS,FUN=function(x{toString(unique(x))}))
C <- data.frame(A,B)
colnames(C)[1] <- "comodity"
colnames(C)[2] <- "Std Issue"
C$comodity <- strsplit(C$comodity, split = ",")

C$`Std Issue` <- strsplit(C$`Std Issue`,split = ",")
C$new <- NA

D <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(C)){

   if(length(C$`Std Issue`[[i]])>1){for(j in 1:length(C$`Std Issue`[[i]]))
     {
       D[j]<- paste(C$comodity[[i]][j],C$`Std Issue`[[i]][j],sep = "-")
     }
       C$new[i]<-paste(D,collapse = ",")

     }
    else 
     { 
       C$new[i] <-paste(C$`Std Issue`[i])
     }
}
```

Comment: How can i post a snippet over here, I have the result which I can not copy and paste over here, please suggest